# Django search method

Tags: python, django

I have done this small piece of code used to search for a given word across several fields of a Django model.

Goal was to have first entries equals to the word, then entries starting by the world and finally just entries containing it.

I would like to have feedback on it :

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""Module created to search a specific term in several fields of a model"""
from itertools import chain
import operator

from django.db.models import Q

__author__ = 'trnsnt'


def search_for_term(model, term, fields, number=10):
    """
    Generic method used to search term on list of fields.
    Return first fields equals to term, then fields starting by the term, and at the end fields containing term
    :param model: Django model class
    :param term: Searched term
    :param fields: Fields to look for
    :param number: Number of wanted response
    :return: List of objects
    """
    searcher = ['iexact', 'istartswith', 'icontains']
    objects = []
    for search in searcher:
        curr_filter = reduce(operator.or_, [Q(('%s__%s' % (field, search), term)) for field in fields])
        # Need to search for number to handle duplicate objects
        objects = uniquify(objects, model.objects.filter(curr_filter)[:number])[:number]
        if len(objects) == number:
            return objects
    return objects


def uniquify(*queryests):
    """Take several queryset and return list of unique object
    :param queryests: QuerySets we want to uniquify
    """
    seen = set()
    return [x for x in chain(*queryests) if not (x in seen or seen.add(x))]
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Is there anything in particular that you're interested in getting feedback or responses on?

Comment: Thanks. I worked with Python & Django for several years, but for now I did not have the opportunity to share on what I am doing. I would like to some advises on what to improve !

Answer (score 3):

Nice doc-strings. I enjoyed seeing your code. I have just a few comments.

**Use built-in functions instead of rolling your own**

My guess would be that you could improve the efficiency of `uniquify` and also make the code more expressive/easier to digest by returning the list version of a union of all the sets in `querysets` rather than rolling your own solution. Something like this should work (I didn't run it):

```
full_set = set().union(*query_sets)
return list(full_set)
```

Another option relying on built-in functionality would be to return a set out of the chaining you already do:

```
return set(chain(*queryests))
```

In fact coming back to this, I think you should return a set. It doesn't seem that you later need a list since you're just checking membership. I believe checking `set` membership is much faster than checking `list` membership.

**Logic**

I apologize if I am misunderstanding your logic, but it seems in `search_for_term` that you want to return early when you find at least `number` number of results. However, right now you only return early if you find exactly that number of results. Wouldn't you want to modify your early return as:

```
    if len(objects) >= number:
        return objects
```

If not it might be helpful to add a comment explaining the logic of returning when you have exactly a certain number of results.

**Little nits**

Notice you've got a typo in your parameter name `queryests`. I would recommend using `snake_case` as in my example above.

Since you're only using `operator.or_`, consider importing just that function.

Comment: Thanks for your review, really instructive. To clarify about `len(objects) == number`, it is because previous line I do `objects = uniquify(queryset)[:number]`, so `len(objects)` cannot be greater than number (am I wrong ?)

Comment: @trnsnt you're not wrong, but you have a slight bug however. What if `number` is `10` and the `'iexact'` query returns `20` results. Then out of the ten firsts, you got two duplicates... You'll be throwing the ten last exact results in favor of one `istartswith`. Kinda counterintuitive.

Comment: if `number` is `10` and `iexact` return 20 results `uniquify(models, queryset[:number])[:number]` will have `len` equals to `number`, no ?

Answer (score 1):

What you're doing here is executing three database queries and combining the results in Python. Potentially the database returns \$3n\$ results, of which you throw away \$2n\$. This is wasted effort. When \$n\$ is small you might be able to live with this, but to handle large \$n\$ it would be a good idea to get the database to run just one query and return just the results you need.

How can you do that? Well, if you were writing plain SQL, then you'd write something like this:

```
SELECT table.*
FROM table, (SELECT 0 AS score
             UNION ALL
             SELECT 1 AS score      
             UNION ALL
             SELECT 2 AS score) AS _s
WHERE _s.score = 0 AND table.field1 ILIKE 'term'
   OR _s.score = 0 AND table.field2 ILIKE 'term'
   OR ...
   OR _s.score = 1 AND table.field1 ILIKE 'term%'
   OR _s.score = 1 AND table.field2 ILIKE 'term%'
   OR ...
   OR _s.score = 2 AND table.field1 ILIKE '%term%'
   OR _s.score = 2 AND table.field2 ILIKE '%term%'
   OR ...
GROUP BY table.id
ORDER BY MIN(_s.score)
LIMIT 10;
```

The idea behind this query is to score each match according to how good it is using a join with a table of scores. The `GROUP BY table.id` clause ensures that a table row is returned at most once; the `ORDER BY` clause ensure that we return the best match.

So you could execute this as a [raw SQL query](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/sql/), perhaps like this:

```
import django.db

_OPS = [('iexact', '{}'), ('istartswith', '{}%'), ('icontains', '%{}%')]
_SCORE = ' UNION ALL '.join('SELECT {} AS score'.format(i)
                            for i in range(len(_OPS)))
_QUERY = '''
SELECT {table}.*
FROM {table}, ({score}) AS _s
WHERE {where}
GROUP BY {table}.{primary_key}
ORDER BY MIN(_s.score)
LIMIT {max_results}
'''

def search_for_term(model, term, fields, max_results=10):
    quote = django.db.connection.ops.quote_name
    table = quote(model._meta.db_table)
    clauses = []
    params = []
    for score, (op, match) in enumerate(_OPS):
        op = django.db.connection.operators[op]
        for field in map(quote, fields):
            clauses.append("_s.score={} AND {}.{} {}"
                           .format(score, table, field, op))
            params.append(match.format(term))
    query = _QUERY.format(table=model._meta.db_table,
                          score=_SCORE,
                          where=' OR '.join(clauses),
                          primary_key=quote(model._meta.pk.name),
                          max_results=max_results)
    return model.objects.raw(query, params)
```

(If the search terms need to contain percent signs or backslashes then you'll need to escape them.)

However, you would almost certainly be much better off using your database's full text search capability. For example, see the documentation for [Sqlite3](https://sqlite.org/fts5.html) or [PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/textsearch-intro.html).